# Can a C++14/17 project use binary libraries compiled using C++11 standard or does the source code need to be recompiled?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, standards, std

Can a binary which was compiled using C++11 be used in a c++14/17 project?
What about a c++14 binary library in a c++17 project?

Or would the source code need to be updated and recompiled using the same standard as the project?

Are there any other ways to include older standard C++ libraries in new standard projects?

Comment: The standard says nothing about this. It depends on your compiler toolchain.

Comment: @RaymondChen Are you able to provide some insight as to what you've seen done in practice?

Comment: In the projects I work on, everything is compiled with exactly the same version of the compiler. When the compiler is upgraded to C++14, the entire project recompiles with the new compiler. That way, there are no mismatches.

Comment: @RaymondChen So all library source code is checked / updated to make sure it complies with the newer standard (assuming the libraries were not forward compatible for some reason)?

Comment: IMHO, this question is equivalent to link libs built by different compiler or different compiler version. Mostly it works but nothing promised.

Comment: It, probably, depends on the contents of your libraries header files. I would build everything.

Comment: @Greg Yes. Changing compilers is not taken lightly.

Comment: For the itanium ABI, TBC, C++17 introduces a breaking change, the noexcept specifier is now part of the mangled name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard has nothing todo with the file format of the binary. That only depends on the compilers/linkers and the OS. So if the compiler vendor changes the ABI ( Application binary interface ), you can not simply link the parts together.

As you can read here, only relevant for gcc:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

gcc introduces with gcc5.1 a new ABI. A history of versions of libraries from gcc and maybe comments to ABI changes can be found here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

So changing from one C++ version to another did not change the ABI but changing the compiler can.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the STL tag in your question. If you use STL in your client interface (which I wouldn’t do), the implementation used in library might differ from implementation you are currently using.

An old version of a fictional STL (or other library) class:

```
// old stl implementation
template < class T >
struct stl_t
{
  T data;
  void set_data( const T d ) { data = d; }
  T get_data() { return data; }
  //...
};
```

A library developed using the old compiler/STL:

```
// client interface file (source delivered to clients)
void f( stl_t<int>& ili ); // old stl assumed

// client interface implementation file (binary delivered to clients)
#include <stl_t> // old stl included!
//...
void f( stl_t<int>& ili ) // old stl used
{
  ili.set_data( 42 );
}
```

The new version of the same fictional STL class:

```
// new stl implementation
template < class T >
struct stl_t
{
  T* data { 0 }; // was T in previous implementation; now it is T*
  void set_data( const T d ) { *data = d; }
  T get_data() { return *data; }
  //...
};
```

Your application mixing the STL versions:

```
// your application
#include <stl_t> // new stl!
#include "library.h" // expects OLD stl but new used

void g()
{
  stl_t<int> a; // NEW stl
  f( a ); // OLD stl expected
  int i = a.get_data();
  // what value is i?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard defnes which features are understandable for compiler in source code and what is provided by standard library. Answer to your question depends on how compatible are ABI versions of your libraries which is defined by your compiler/toolchain version/implementation. For example, because of `std::string` ABI change between GCC 4.x and 5.x libraries built by them won't be inter-linkable.